# DocumentDb and floating point truncation

Tags: c#, double, ieee-754, azure-cosmosdb, truncation

Hi I'm playing around with DocumentDb and are migrating some data into it. I saw that DocumentDb truncated "8.333333333333333333333333333" into "8.33333333333334".

What I understand so does DocumentDb support: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format standard which I understand is the same as C# Double?

But if I run double.Parse("8.333333333333333333333333333") I get "8.3333333333333339".

My main problem is that I want to be able to do the same truncation with C# code as DocumentDb does. But I don't understand how.

Comment: I suspect the difference is in the parsing rather than the storage. You could always convert to a C# Double client-side and store whatever that conversion produces if consistency is your primary worry.

That said, Neither 8.3333333333333339 nor 8.33333333333334 are the best approximations. If your strategy requires that you rely upon the significance of the last few digits of a floating point number, it's a risky strategy.

If you need it to be perfect, you might want to consider using a 3rd party BigDecimal type or C#'s built-in BigRational type and storing it as a string in DocumentDB.

Comment: Thanks for the help on the alternatives, I will look into those. But first I want to know why DocumentDb is transforming "8.333333333333333333333333333" to "8.33333333333334". I know that the .NET SDK is using NewtonSoft, I've tested to to deserialize "8.333333333333333333333333333" with newtonsoft and it doesn't truncate. So the truncation is probably done server side on documentdb

Comment: DocumentDB team member here. You're right that the server side performs truncation. As to why, it's for portability with JavaScript and other programming language platforms.

Comment: What algorithm does it use to truncate, and how can I do the same truncation within .NET? I tried to set "8.333333333333333333333333333"  to an javascript variable but it converted it to "8.333333333333334". The correct ending number but the amount of decimals is not matching. The one in Javascript gives med 15 decimals meanwhile the one that documentdb gave me had 14.

Comment: @NPehrsson Let's not start a discussion, with new questions, here in comments. Either take this to chat (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) or ask a new question. Thanks.

Comment: Good point, let's get back to the root question. How does DocumentDb truncate the number?